# Google Places Autocomplete Types

Tags: google-places-api

I need is an autocomplete list that searches based on type of establishment from Google Places API. Currently, it seems that Google has limited their Places autocomplete API to types like establishment or geolocation. I need is a type exactly like the Google Places search where you can limit results to establishments of type food or bars, etc.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I would prefer to stick with a Google API, but feel free to suggest other APIs.

Comment: As this is currently not a feature of the Places API, if you think that it would be useful, please submit a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).